# How does Regression works in XGboost?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

How does XGboost is performing the regression tasks?

Ex- We know that for a classification problem in Boosting, it is punishing the mis-classified points & the weightage is given more for them in the next stump.

How does the weightage is given in case of regression?

Comment: please use google for this type of questions....you can find nice tutorials that explains it clearly

Comment: Question is too broad to have useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.let’s go through a simple regression example, using Decision Trees as the base predictors (of course, Gradient Boosting also works great with regression tasks). This is called Gradient Tree Boosting, or Gradient Boosted Regression Trees (GBRT).

2.First, let’s fit a DecisionTreeRegressor to the training set (the ouput is a noise quadratic fit)

3.next we will train the second regression tree on the residuals made by the first regression tree.

4.Then we train a third regressor on the residual errors made by the second predictor

5.Now we have an ensemble containing three trees. It can make predictions on a new instance simply by adding up the predictions of all the trees: